# Magento 2: Can't place the order corectly after return back from payment (3ds page)

Tags: magento2, checkout, module, payment, callback

I'm developing a payment module for Magento 2 and stuck at some point.
and I already checked the similar questions,
I send a callback URL with the post of data to PSP to get the customer back to it with the result of the payment, which is actually a controller for handling the response and make the transaction. But I have a problem that even that order paid or failed it always redirected to the cart and not adding order to the history.
And if I try to use getQuote() or dealing with order object always return empty.

Here is the form sending with placeOrder():

```
    <div class="primary">
            <form data-bind=" mageInit: {'validation': []}" class="form" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="Payment-gateway-website" method="POST" id="cardForm">
                <fieldset class="fieldset">
                    <input name="callback_url" type="hidden" data-bind="value: getBaseUrl()"  />
                    <input name="api_key" type="hidden" data-bind="value: getApiKey()" />
                   <input name="amount" type="hidden" data-bind="value: getAmount()" />
                    <!-- TODO: get store currency as a value -->
                    <input name="card[type]" type="hidden" value="creditcard" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="card[3ds]" value="true" />
                    <div class="control">
                        <input id="credit_card_name" name="card[name]" type="text" value="" />
                      <input class ="input-text" autocomplete="off" id="credit_card_number" name="card[number]" type="text"
                        />
                        <input class="input-text" autocomplete="off" id="credit_card_cvc" name="card[cvc]" type="text" value="" data-validate="
                        {required:true, 
                        validate-cc-cvv:true,
                        validate-number:true}"
                        />
                        <input id="credit_card_month" name="card[month]" type="text" value="" />
                        <input id="credit_card_year" name="card[year]" type="text" value="" />
                    </div>
                    <button class="action primary checkout"
                            type="submit"
                            data-bind="
                            attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
                            css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()},
                            enable: (getCode() == isChecked())
                            "
                            disabled>
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
                    </button>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
```

And here is the controller of callback URL :

```
   public function execute()
   {
    $order = $this->getOrder();
    $returnUrl = $this->getHelper()->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success');
    if($_GET['status'] == 'paid') {
        $this->getHelper()->processOrder($order);
        $returnUrl = $this->getHelper()->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success');
    } else {
        $returnUrl = $this->getHelper()->getUrl('checkout/cart');
    } 
    $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($returnUrl);
    }
    protected function getOrder()
    {
       return $this->_orderFactory->create()->loadByIncrementId(
        $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrderId());
    }
    protected function getHelper()
    {
        return $this->_helper;
    }
```

and here is the helper processPayment function :

```
      public function processOrder($order) {

    if ($order->getState() != $order::STATE_PROCESSING) {
        $order->setStatus($order::STATE_PROCESSING);
        $order->setState($order::STATE_PROCESSING);
        $order->save();
        $order->addStatusToHistory( $order::STATE_PROCESSING , 'namespace_module :: Order has been paid.' );
        $order->save();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestion,
I'll appreciate any help.